# JQuery - Cannot read property top of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been receiving this error whenever try running this piece of Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Card-Right-Sec").style.top = $("#Card-Left-Sec").style.top;
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>       at :1:59

I'm basically trying to align two elements with each other no matter how much the screen resizes but that has not been working out too well for me...
I'm ready to take **Any** suggestions at this point.

Comment: Can you share your markup? Even more helpful, a small example in a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `style` property for jQuery Object, use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method on jQuery object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Card-Right-Sec").css('top', $("#Card-Left-Sec").css('top'));
});
```

---

Or get DOM object by index or using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method and update the style property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Card-Right-Sec")[0].style.top = $("#Card-Left-Sec")[0].style.top;
});
```

Comment: This code did not return an error, but once I tried running it console the elements did not align, could it be a problem with how I'm approaching this?

Comment: @Zyad-O : this would apply the style property.... there may be something wrong with the logic...

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing jQuery objects with DOM elements. Only real DOM elements have the `style` property; you need to access index `[0]` before using this property.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Card-Right-Sec")[0].style.top = $("#Card-Left-Sec")[0].style.top;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `.css function` from jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Card-Right-Sec").css('top',$("#Card-Left-Sec").css('top'));
 });
```